# Keycloak behind nginx reverse proxy in kubernetes keep redirecting

Tags: angular, kubernetes, nginx, keycloak

I have angular application in kubernetes. When we using keycloak url with kube ingress everything works OK. Problem is when we are trying to use with nginx.
In angular environments I set just context path:

```
kcUri: '/auth'
```

and then in nginx configuration:

```
    location  /auth/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass              http://kc-service.namespace/auth/;
    }
```

problem is that this is not working and application keeps redirecting and adding new stuf to url like:

```
%2525252526redirect_uri%252525253Dhttps%3A%25252525252F%25252525252F
```

any Idea how to fix it ?